# RoR Grape API | How to invoke an endpoint in one API from another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I'm using Grape API with Ruby on Rails. I would like to invoke a POST endpoint in Api::A from an endpoint in Api::B, where both are mounted under the Api class.

```
class Api < Grape::API
  mount Api::A
  mount Api::B
end

class Api::Base < Grape::API
  # common functionality
end

# contains endpoints pertaining to entity A
class Api::A < Api::Base
  namespace :a do
    params do
     ...
    end
    post '' begin
      ...
    end
  end
end

# contains endpoints pertaining to entity B
class Api::B < Api::Base
  namespace :b do
    params do
     ...
    end
    post '' begin
      # How do I directly invoke Api::A's POST endpoint?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure I comprehend what you are trying to achieve but if both should do the same thing then you should be able to abstract this out and mount it in both locations. See [Remounting](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#remounting) in the docs

Comment: @engineersmnky Nice - remounting may def. work here as an alternative. Although, if it is possible to invoke one endpoint from another as described above that would still be ideal. The logic pertains to entity A. The call from entity B is more a convenience method that fills in some parameters for a certain view - avoiding a sequence of calls on the front end. An overload if you will.

Comment: @engineersmnky that's all the endpoint is doing - it constructs a query as per request parameters, grabs the data and returns it. But there is quite a lot going on in constructing the query such that I would hate to duplicate it - and refactoring would be a pain. As such, simply being able to invoke the endpoint would simplify things greatly.

Comment: "there is quite a lot going on in constructing the query" this is what belongs in a different place. All you would need to do is copy this logic into a different object and pass the params to that object. The refactoring should be fairly simple and this pattern is much more maintable and extensible in the future. I am not saying you can't do what you are trying to do (although I don't have an answer to that righ this second) I am saying you probably shouldn't

Comment: @engineersmnky. The logic for constructing the query is quite large and spread out over multiple files - the Api::Base class, Api::A class, and several other Api::XXX classes use it. Ripping it out of there is a large project. I don't disagree that it would be better placed elsewhere, but its not a simple task. So - again - the most convenient solution would be to simply be able to call the other endpoint. Other frameworks provide this - not sure why GrapeAPI would not.

Comment: So I took a look at this and you are not going to be able to do what you want without making your own request, `Net:HTTP` or otherwise, to "/a" and then returning that. There is no real feasible way to "call" that route from within the block body of another route because the environment (`env`) controls so much and has been so mutated by this point that trying to alter it so suit your needs would be nearly impossible and certainly not worth the effort. If you would like to see exactly what you would be dealing with simply add this to the current body and look at the logs `puts request.env`

Comment: @engineersmnky damn! Well I really appreciate you looking into it. I guess I'll go the refactoring route then.